# Can user activity be captured on a unix server with bash or Python

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu

I work off a server along with a number of other people, who, because of unexplained occurrences, change files, symlinks, etc. Unfortunately, all have the same level of file system rights. Is there a straightforward way to capture activity: login/logout time (I know the 'last' command shows this), files changed (deleted, added, etc.), and symlinks created, changed or deleted? I'm wondering if it's more straight forward to do something like this in bash or Python, and which direction to go? Thanks for all help.

Comment: If it's a unix system, why not simply restrict `group` and `other` access to the files and directories keeping only the owner rights in place? Unless you all use `root` or the same account for some reason (and must stop that!) this would prevent them from accessing your files and directories, no matter their "rights"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you really should lock your user accounts down on your server. But if you really want to monitor activity within the file system, you've got a couple of options.

1. Write a script to parse their bash history on logout, and save the log out time (poor)
2. Install [iwatch](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html), then point it at the locations to monitor, and write a script to record pertinent information whenever something changes to a log file.

If you want to monitor *user* activity, as if you are watching over their shoulder, that's a little harder. Especially because some things, such as sftp, don't actually make any entries in bash_history. It's an entirely different subsystem.

The best thing to do is just monitor the areas of the filesystem that the users have access to for changes and log them, which is another reason to lock down your users. Linux has user folders for a reason. Everybody gets their own sandbox so that they don't touch each other.

Comment: -Yeah, I'm aware of that, but the level of politics involved in my environment is uncanny ... can't make anyone feel denigrated.

Comment: @suffa thought so. Iwatch should do the job though, and it's *far* better than a kludgey roll your own solution.